# Harry Potter fan fic about him going missing with Voldemort after the war

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I read, about four or five years ago, a fan fic about Harry going missing for two years after the war with Voldemort, and when he comes back, Ginny has two kids, and Harry is the father but he doesn't know.

In those two years, he's been tortured by Voldemort with memories in a dark room.

I'm 90% sure I read it on fanfiction.net, because that was the only fan fic site I remember going to.

I don't remember the length of the fic, unfortunately.